# Sum number of columns with difference of start rows

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

```
sn  a   b   c   d       Sum
sr  7   6   4   8       


1   17  10  20  12      0
2   15  8   20  10      0
3   13  6   21  9       0
4   12  4   21  7       20
5   11  3   22  6       20
6   10  2   22  5       31
7   9   2   23  5       45
8   8   1   23  4       54
9   7   1   23  3       50
10  6   1   24  3       46
11  6   1   24  2       44
12  5   0   25  2       41
```

I am looking to sum the column a, b, c & d in one column that the starting row is in the row sr (start row) the results are in column Sum. I am doing this with this function:

```
=IF($O12>=P$9,HLOOKUP(P$8,Sheet3!$P$8:$S$23,5+$O12-P$9,FALSE),0)+IF($O12>=Q$9,HLOOKUP(Q$8,Sheet3!$P$8:$S$23,5+$O12-Q$9,FALSE),0)+IF($O12>=R$9,HLOOKUP(R$8,Sheet3!$P$8:$S$23,5+$O12-R$9,FALSE),0)+IF($O12>=S$9,HLOOKUP(S$8,Sheet3!$P$8:$S$23,5+$O12-S$9,FALSE),0).
```

Assume that my table is on the area O8:U23.
Problem that I have a large table of 300 columns and 1000 rows of data.

Could you please to help me to get a VBA a script/function or easy excel function to resolve this.
Best regards
Hafed

Comment: Can't you just copy the formula down 300 rows? Not that it can't be done in VBA, I'm just not sure exactly what you are calculating.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below formula in Column G:

In G5 `=IF(A5>B$2-1,B5,0)+IF(A5>C$2-1,C5,0)+IF(A5>D$2-1,D5,0)+IF(A5>E$2-1,E5,0)`

Copy the formula down till end of your data.

Note that in your sample table you have shown 4 columns worth of data, so my formula contains 4 separate IF evaluations, however in your actual workbook for area O8:U23 you may have 6-7 columns, so you will need to add the remaining IF conditions on similar lines.

[image]